# How to execute all functions from crtp base classes in a variadic derived class?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, crtp

I have a [CRTP](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) derived class that is a variadic template of all the CRTP base classes it could inherit. I want to execute a function from every inherited class (in this example the print function) in a method of the derived class (the printAll function). How can i accomplish that?

```
// Base Class 1
template<typename Derived>
struct Mult
{
  void print()
  {
    int a = (static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)).m_a;
    int b = (static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)).m_b;
    std::cout << "a * b: " << a * b << "\n";
  }
};

// Base Class 2
template<typename Derived>
struct Add
{
  void print()
  {
    int a = (static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)).m_a;
    int b = (static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)).m_b;
    std::cout << "a + b: " << a + b << "\n";
  }
};

template<template<typename> typename... Bases>
struct Derived : public Bases<Derived<Bases...>>...
{
  int m_a, m_b;
  Derived(int a, int b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
  void printAll()
  {
    // Should execute the print method of all the derived classes
    this->print();
  }
};


int main()
{
  Derived<Mult, Add> d(2, 3);
  // should print:
  // a + b: 5
  // a * b: 6
  d.printAll();
}
```

Comment: `Mult` is not a class template, and cannot be a parameter to `Derived`. It also uses undefined name `Derived`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, have edited it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  void printAll()
  {
    auto _ = {(Bases<Derived<Bases...>>::print(), 0) ...};
  }
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/XTJHT27584)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [*fold expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), one of the new language features in C++17:

```
void printAll()
{
    (Bases<Derived>::print(), ...);
}
```